# Should Redis Sentinel Monitor Each Master in a cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

Does it require sentinel to monitor each master in the cluster with a distinct service name, or just one of the 3 masters in the cluster?

My current config is 3 masters, 3 slaves, and 3 sentinel instances. Each instance of sentinel is monitoring each master. master1, master2, master3. I haven't seen any documentation that has more than a single master, and the redis documentation isn't real clear.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by running a test myself. Yes, in a cluster configuration you need to monitor each master in order for failover to occur.

Comment: how is it possible to have more than 1 master in redis-cluster? @aaron